# I have to place two calls to web API, first for validating the user and second for retrieving user details if validation is successful

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have to place two calls to web API, first for validating the user and second for retrieving user details if validation is successful. If client side app directly calls the retrieveUserDetails (i.e. the second call), how can I prevent this? Also, how to achieve the correct way of implementing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making 2 calls to retrieve user details will be a very chatty way to design this feature. Right way is to have one single call to the API and if the validation fails the API should respond with proper error code so that the client can respond accordingly.